# Let's ask more Tanakh questions

Tags: discussion, challenge

Inspired by the [weekly topic challenge](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281/idea-weekly-topic-challenges) on Jewish Life and Learning - Stack Exchange, I think it would be helpful (and hopefully a fun challenge) to ask questions on a specific topic for some period of time.  (A week would be good, but we don't have the ability to change the system message yet so it will probably take a little longer to get organized.)

The particular challenge I'd like to propose is to ask questions about the Tanakh.  If you happen to be Jewish it won't be much of a challenge, but for the rest of us, it might require some effort to ask a question about the Old Testament from a Jewish perspective.  As if reading my mind, Soldernal just asked a [model question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/448/68).

Will you ask one question that correctly uses the [tanakh](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tanakh) tag?

Comment: I don't know who is reading whose mind, cause I saw that weekly topic challenge thing too and was wondering whether we could try it here. Thanks for starting this.

Comment: @Soldarnal: Obviously, future challenges would be decided by the community rather than just me alone.  Assuming this idea works...

Comment: @Monica: I tried my hand at the [tag:old-testament] wiki.  (It's waiting on a review as well.)  Thanks for taking up the [tag:tanakh] wiki.  It looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's been a week since I proposed this challenge and I'd say it's gone well.  We've doubled the number of Tanakh questions from 8 to 16.  We've seen some [cross](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/451/did-jephthah-have-pets) [pollination](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11035/what-else-could-have-come-out-of-yiftachs-house) between here and the Jewish Life & Learning Stack Exchange.  And personally I had a lot of fun and learned more than I had hoped or imagined.  Thank you all for participating.

But now what?  Well for one thing, don't stop asking Tanakh questions or tagging them as such.  We're building a broad community and having content that interests our whole group will help us grow.  Some of our very best questions are in this category.

For another thing, I'd like to continue having regular challenges with the idea of encouraging content that we lack or to coincide with some seasonal event.  We can use more high-quality questions and if you, dear reader, ask a question, I'm sure it will be excellent.  I've looked at my calendar and I have a few ideas for the next couple of months, but I'd really like this to be a community effort.  (And if it's just me pushing my ideas, you can be sure it will die off soon.)

So thanks again and stay tuned for another challenge from me to you.