# Let's remember Peace

Tags: discussion, tags, challenge

Last week, I proposed a [challenge](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/lets-ask-more-tanakh-questions) to ask more [tanakh](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tanakh) questions.  And I thought I'd make another challenge this week.

Friday, November 11 at 11am marks the 93<sup>rd</sup> anniversary of the [Armistice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armistice_Day) between the Allies and Germany.  Even up to the [last minute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armistice_with_Germany#Last_casualties), the terrible fighting raged on in ["the war to end wars"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_war_to_end_war).  Would that it were so.

The Bible (the Tanakh and New Testament) talk often about peace: our failure to find it and our hope, from God, to achieve it.  [*Shalom*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shalom) is much more than just an absence of conflict, but a deep and powerful well-being.  In the face of the evil in the world, let's remember peace—*shalom*.

Please use [shalom](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shalom) if you happen to ask a question that fits in the next week.  Also, I suggest linking back to this question in the comments so we can build some momentum for the challenge.

Comment: I've kicked this off with a [question](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/516/68) about Melchizedek.

Comment: Here's another [question](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/527/68).  This time from a prophesy in Daniel.

Answer (score 1):

My vote is to create a [shalom](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shalom) tag. It's a large enough concept that it should garner a number of questions even if not a lot. I think topical tags would be helpful for anyone doing biblical theology or even just a topical study, which is why I created, for instance, a [temple](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temple) tag. I feel like it provides a quick way to access all the tough questions on a topic.

Comment: Oh!  I guess I was overly worried that my little project would pollute the tag pool.  If this seems to not be a problem with most people, I'll change my advice.  (Thanks for the feedback.)